# 3 Player game in C using Signals

Tags: c, unix, parallel-processing, signals, signal-handling

I have been trying to develop a 3 player game in C using signals but it is not giving desired output.

```
#define _POSIX_SOURCE   //to use functionality from the POSIX.1 standard as ANCI C does not support kill()
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>

void action(){}
void child(char *);

int main(){
  pid_t pid1, pid2, pid3;

  printf("This is a 3-players game with a referee\n\n");
  if((pid1=fork()) == 0) child("TOTO");
  sleep(1);
  if((pid2=fork()) == 0) child("TITI");
  sleep(1);
  if((pid3=fork()) == 0) child("TUTU");

  sleep(1);
 while(1){
    signal(SIGUSR1, action);
    printf("Refree: TOTO plays\n\n");
    kill(pid1, SIGUSR1);
    pause();
    printf("Refree: TITI plays\n\n");
    kill(pid2, SIGUSR1);
    pause();
    printf("Refree: TUTU plays\n\n");
    kill(pid3, SIGUSR1);
    pause();
  }
}
void child(char *s){
  int points=0, dice;
  srand(time(NULL));

  while(1){
    signal(SIGUSR1, action);  // block myself
    pause();
    sleep(1);
    printf("%s: playing my dice\n", s);
    dice = rand() % 10 + 1;
    printf("%s: got %d points\n", s, dice);
    points+=dice;
    printf("%s: Total so far %d\n\n", s, points);
    sleep(3);
    if(points >= 100){
      printf("%s: game over I won\n", s);
      kill(0, SIGTERM);
    }
    kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);
  } 
}
```

Output I get is:

```
This is a 3-players game with a referee

Refree: TOTO plays

TOTO: playing my dice
TOTO: got 8 points
TOTO: Total so far 8

Refree: TITI plays

TITI: playing my dice
TITI: got 2 points
TITI: Total so far 2

User defined signal 1
```

It never shows "TUTU" playing dice and terminates using User Defined Signal 1 which is registered as a blank signal. The program should terminate only after a player wins.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

When the referee catches TOTO's signal, it's disposition is reset to `SIG_DFL`, so TITI's signal really kills him. The referee must call `signal(SIGUSR1, action)` three times per loop, before each `kill()`.

An alternative is to `#define _BSD_SOURCE` (read the Portability section of `man 2 signal` carefully), which imposes a BSD semantics of not resetting a disposition

Comment: Just added #define _BSD_SOURCE and now it works like a charm.